# Border appears around material-ui Chip component inside at normal zoom but not when zoomed in or out, on all browsers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

#### Edit

I have found that if I add the line `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the root `div` for the `Chip`, the problem corrects itself. However, that is automatically being added by `inline-styler` or something, and I really wish it would *stop adding vendor prefixes* for reasons not just including this one.

Any more insight is appreciated.

I have a really odd problem with the `material-ui` `Chip` Component. It's pretty self-explanatory if you look below at the same `Chip` at different zoom levels:

#### Zoomed out - 75%

[image: 75%]

#### Zoomed out - 90%

[image: 90%]

#### Normal zoom - 100%

[image: 100%]

#### Zoomed in - 110%

[image: 110%]

I've never seen anything like this before and I am curious as to what it could be. FYI, it is the same problem whether using `Chrome` or `Safari` or `Firefox`, although on some browsers (notably `Safari`) it doesn't work at any zoom level. Note that I am testing on OS X.

The code for the `Chip` is:

```
        <Chip
          key={`ffeffef`}>
          <Avatar size={32}>B</Avatar>
          Blah blah
        </Chip>
```

When I do not use the `Avatar` it **sometimes** works but I think it only appears like it does when it "hot loads" the component, not after a fresh refresh. It is a very odd problem.

The CSS does not indicate it should have a border as it does.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because `<Chip>` component renders a `div` with `type="button"` attribute, but in last versions of [`materialize-css`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css) there is set a rule:

```
[type=reset], [type=submit], button, html [type=button] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

I've fixed it by setting:

```
[type=button]{
  -webkit-appearance: none
}
```

In a global css file.

By the way, no only `<Chip>` component is affected, I've run in this issue with `<ListItem>`. Searching issues on github, I saw that people complain about other components too. Hope maintainers will fix this soon.